# Angular Pipe not working when selecting the browser suggestion for input field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

I am using the built-in pipe **titlecase** on an input field - *username* in a reactive form. It is working properly only when i am typing in the input field and its not working when i select from the browser suggestion for that input field, even when i focused out.

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNames.bind(this)]),
        'email': new FormControl('abc@test.com', [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails)
      }),
      'gender': new FormControl('male'),
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    });
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="userData">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="username">Username</label>
             <input
                  type="text"
                  id="username"
                  formControlName="username"
                  class="form-control"
                  [value]="signupForm.get('userData.username').value | titlecase">
                  <span *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.username').errors['required']">
                      This field is required
                  </span>
          </div>
         ...
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

When i am typing it is working fine

[image]

When i am selecting from the browser selection it is not working
Though i focused out of the input field its still in uppercase.

[image]
Can someone help on what i am doing wrong.

---

@Haifeng Zhang This is the scenario i mentioned in the question, i replicated in your [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtneec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2nd edit:**
[image]
Check the very last action in the GIF, I type in space and `ADD` transforms to `Add`

That's how `titlecase` work, the definition is:

> Transforms text to title case. Capitalizes the first letter of each word, and transforms the rest of the word to lower case. Words are delimited by any whitespace character, such as a space, tab, or line-feed character.

**1st edit:**

I use tempref and it works for me:
[Demo is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtneec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

app.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
  <div formGroupName="userData">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="username" #username [value]="username.value | titlecase">
  </div>
  <pre>{{ signUpForm.value | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

app.component.ts:

```
 constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
      userData: this.fb.group({
        username: '',
        email: ''
      })
    });
  }
```

It also works when I copy a uppercase 'ABC' into the input field

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Haifeng Zhang for taking your time and answering, I had the issue when i was selecting the browser suggested selection which had Uppercase value. It was working fine when i was entering the input in my approach. Can you try removing the pipe, then save the form with uppercase input so that the browser will suggest next time when you type the same input. Next use the pipe and select the browser suggestion and check if thats transformed.

Comment: @Avinash I upload a GIF picture and also a StackBlitz demo:)

Comment: i replicated the issue in the same stackblitz demo you posted and updated my question with the gif, please check on that.

Comment: @Avinash I saw that and the definition of `titlecase` said that the words are delimited by space, tab or line-feed character, the way you *did will not trigger* `titlecase` that's why it didn't work in the scenario. RezaRahmati's suggestion will handle this case properly

Comment: That was informative @Haifeng Zhang , then in the approach i did also it should work after i select the browser suggestion and then add a space.

Answer (score 2):

I used another approach which is subscribing to valuechange

see live demo here at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-pipe)

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      'userData': this.fb.group({
        'username': [null, [Validators.required]],
        'email': ['abc@test.com', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      }),
      'gender': ['male'],
      'hobbies': this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.signupForm.controls.userData.get('username').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.signupForm.controls.userData.patchValue(
        {
          username: this.titleCasePipe.transform(val)
        }, 
        { emitEvent: false })
    })
  }
```

and

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="userData">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="username">Username</label>
             <input
                  type="text"
                  id="username"
                  formControlName="username"
                  class="form-control"
                  >
                  <span *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.username').errors && signupForm.get('userData.username').errors['required']">
                      This field is required
                  </span>
          </div>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks @RezaRahmati for the approach, i commented the place where we subscribe to valueChanges in your code and saved the form with uppercase input, next i uncommented and tried by selecting from the browser suggestion. It worked fine in your approach. But can you help on what i was doing wrong in my approach and letting me know why it wasn't working in my approach.